# Is "in this part" a correct phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Is "in this part" a correct phrase? For instance, if we say

> In this part of the essay we talk about...

is this all right? I am trying to translate a construction from my language and "in this part" feels like the equivalent, but I am not sure if this is proper English.

Comment: It seems acceptable to me, subject to context of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the word **part**.

- part of an essay, book, text, etc.

The problem is the overall sentence.

We would actually express it like this:

**This part of the essay discusses** etc. And not: "in this part" for this sentence.

in this part sounds like Spanish or French.

Please note: I am not saying that "in this part of the book" is not idiomatic. I am saying it would not be used in a sentence such as the one  you posted.

Comment: Thank you! I felt that it sounded a bit odd (as a matter of fact, my native language is a romance language). So my sentence should be "This first part of the essay talks about/ presents..."? LE: now I saw that you used the verb "discusses". Would "presents" also work?

Comment: @JustAnAmateur Yes, I could tell it was a Romance language. An essay discusses or presents a topic. Don't use talks about, that is more for people. Also, avoid we unless it was written by more than one person....:)

Comment: thank you very much :) I figure that in most cases like this one "we" can be replaced by a passive voice construction.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I only thought about this now: would "this first part of the essay..." be all right? I think it would, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur I would use that if I were speaking, not writing. The first part of the essay